Attached a local file to EPMDocument in Winchill by RESTApis
I want to attached a local file to EPMDocument in Winchill by RESTApis.
But i can not see any document about this.
When working around i see 2 possible ways
Way 1:
+> Find some way to upload the file to server's content cache. Then get the encodedCCD property
+> Using encodedCCD to add to the request create EPMDocument. API: **POST Windchill/servlet/rest/v1/wgm/workspaces/{workspaceId}/store **
Way 2:
+> Associate EPMDocument to a WTDocument
+> Attach the file to WTDocument
I not have any experience in Winchill, so can anybody have faced with similar problems, please help me
Thank you

This isn't really a coding question. It's a question about a specific product, Windchill. You should try their support or community rather than Stack Overflow.
